# tsql - return duplicate row id's in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have identified the 'duplicate records' in a table.  Although, I claim they are duplicates, they are but the PK is an identity column - so they are not truly duplicates (but based on the other columns - they are).

I have this data currently in a table with the following format:

```
ID -> identity column 
Row -> indicates the sequential row number 
RowNumber -> indicates that two of the rows are identical
```

for example:

```
ID    Row      RowNumber
500    1        1000 
501    2        1000 
305    1        1050 
306    2        1050
```

I would like to return just the ID's in a single row for each row number

For example, the result set of the above would be:

```
500  501
305  306
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So are those supposed to appear in separate columns, or one column with spaces between them? What is the highest value for `Row`?

Comment: will there only ever be 2 duplicates or could there be several duplicates so the result would be several columns wide

Comment: They should be two separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

One way, use `ROW_NUMBER` with the [`OVER`-clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,Row,RowNumber, 
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY RowNumber
                              ORDER BY Row)
    FROM CTE
)
SELECT ID,Row,RowNumber FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

If you want to delete the duplicates replace the `SELECT` with

```
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table 
(
ID         INT,
"Row"      INT,
RowNumber  INT
)

INSERT INTO #Table 
VALUES
  (500,1,1000),
  (501,2,1000),
  (305,1,1050),
  (306,2,1050)
```

`CASE` statements work:

```
SELECT 
    RowNumber,
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Row" = 1 THEN ID ELSE NULL END) AS "1", 
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Row" = 2 THEN ID ELSE NULL END) AS "2"
FROM #Table
GROUP BY RowNumber
```

[`PIVOT` is an alternative](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT
    RowNumber,
    "1",
    "2"
FROM
    (SELECT "Row",ID, RowNumber FROM #Table) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
    MAX(ID) 
    FOR "Row" IN ("1","2")
    ) AS PivotTable
```